# For values less than 1 Math.acosh() returns NaN

Tags: javascript, node.js, math

I were solving a Keta In codewars the Keta is to find If the given sides can form a triangle, **I solved the problem** but when I tried to find the angle  A using The law of cosines
 I find that **For values less than 1 Math.acosh() returns NaN.** how can I find angle A?

```
function isTriangle(a,b,c)
{
  if(a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0){

    let angelA, cosAInverse;

    //law of cosines CosA = (b^2 + c^2 - a^2) / (2 * b * c);
    angelA = (Math.pow(b,2) + Math.pow(c, 2) - Math.pow(a,2)) / (2 * b * c);

    //Math.acosh(0.852);
    cosAInverse = Math.acosh(angelA); // expected value 28.95502437

    console.log(cosAInverse); // NaN

    return cosAInverse;

  }
  return false;
}
var xx = isTriangle(1,2,2);
console.log(xx);
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Inverse_hyperbolic_cosine - it's always good to know your Maths before using it

Comment: Also, if you were instead trying to use Math.acos ... Math.acos(0.852) is *31.570128673595704 degrees* ... so you're wrong in what you expect I guess - however, Math.acos(0.875) - which is what you **would** expect given 1,2,2 arguments, is definitely *28.955024371859846 degrees* - - but `Math.acosh` is nothing to do with `Math.acos`

Comment: Thank you JaromandaX you are absolutely right I thought Math.acosh == cos^-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `Math.acosh()` but `Math.acos()`

Comment: Thank you Huegelkoenig and JaromandaX you are absolutely right I thought Math.acosh == cos^-1 which is wrong